# One of my global variable used inside runnable thread assign a value and cant use that variable in other function

Tags: java, android

//a decalre global variable assign a value inside a runnable thread and cant         use in Toast of next function;

```
public class A extends Activity
{
    String a;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceStat);
        setContentView(R.layout.a);

        threadPart();
        reuseThreadValue();
    }

    public void threadPart()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                a = "you can use this";// here i assign a value in variable
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void reuseThreadValue()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a, 1000).show();
        // i cant use the same variable with assign value here
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: ok thak you for suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

I think as variable a in threadPart() function is assigned on different thread, reuseThreadValue() gets called before the variable gets assigned.

Comment: I dont know what you mean to say

Comment: I mean in threadPart() variable assignment is asynchronous while reuseThreadValue() is synchronous

Comment: I mean that you have done "threadPart() variable assignment asynchronously but reuseThreadValue() is synchronous" hence reuseThreadValue() may run before the assignment statement

Comment: can you please write a code for this it will be very help ful for me